# change default one column width of google keep with Chrome or Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, css

When I open google keep site and switch to the one column view with latest Chrome or Firefox browser, the column is not wide enough for me, because I use a external monitor.

I have installed the Stylish extension and how can I change the default one column width?

Answer (score 0):

Having also tried to overcome this, a workaround is to open the Google Keep note in question, and click on the '**more**' option (3 vertical dots) located at the bottom of the keep note and select '**Copy to Google Doc**'.

Then, just open the file. Note that document formatting is also inherited which is a nice touch. A small extra step, but should get you where you're going.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I want.